# Implementing a toString to print the content of a linked list

Tags: java, list, tostring

So I'm trying to work with a linked stack class and I can get the following code to print:

```
STACK TESTING    
The stack contains:

4

8

8

9

The size of the stack is: 3

The stack contains:
```

But I'm having trouble implementing the toString to print out the rest to get a final result of:

```
STACK TESTING

The stack contains:

empty

4

8

8

9

The size of the stack is: 3

The stack contains:

9

7

3
```

I have a feeling its something very basic that needs to be done, but I tend to over think all things. I initially tried to create an instance of the class and then call toString() on it, but It doesn't do what I wanted. If I happen to try something else I tend to get a message of `cannot convert from LinearNode<T> to blah blah blah`.  What is the best way to actually get the rest of the content to print?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
    public class Murray_A05Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedStack<Integer> stack = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
        System.out.println("STACK TESTING");
        System.out.println("The stack contains:\n" + stack.toString());
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(7);
        stack.push(4);
        System.out.println(stack.peek());
        stack.pop();        
        stack.push(9);
        stack.push(8);
        System.out.println(stack.peek());        
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
        System.out.println(stack.peek());        
        System.out.println("The size of the stack is: " + stack.size());
        System.out.println("The stack contains:\n" + stack.toString());        

    } // End of method header.

    public static class LinkedStack<T> implements StackADT<T> {
        private int count;  
        private LinearNode<T> top; // serves as node class

     // Creating an empty stack
        public LinkedStack() {
            count = 0;
            top = null;
        }

     // Adds the specified element to the top of this stack.      
        @Override
        public void push(T element) {
            LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);
            temp.setNext(top);
            top = temp;
            count++;
        }

        public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

                T result = top.getElement();
                top = top.getNext();
                count--;

             return result;
         }

         public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException {
            return top.getElement();    
         }

         public boolean isEmpty() {
             return (top == null);   
         }

         public int size() {
             return count;
         }

            /**
             * Returns a string representation of this stack. The string has the
             * form of each element printed on its own line, with the top most
             * element displayed first, and the bottom most element displayed last.
             * If the list is empty, returns the word "empty".
             * @return a string representation of the stack
             */

           public String toString() {
               //String LinkedStack = "null";
               //return LinkedStack.toString();
               return top;
           } // End of the toString method.
    } // End of method header.
} // End of class header.
```

LinearNode:

```
public class LinearNode<T>
{
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;

    /**
     * Creates an empty node.
     */
    public LinearNode()
    {
        next = null;
        element = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a node storing the specified element.
     * @param elem element to be stored
     */
    public LinearNode(T elem)
    {
        next = null;
        element = elem;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the node that follows this one.
     * @return reference to next node
     */
    public LinearNode<T> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the node that follows this one.
     * @param node node to follow this one
     */
    public void setNext(LinearNode<T> node)
    {
        next = node;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element stored in this node.
     * @return element stored at the node
     */
    public T getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the element stored in this node.
     * @param elem element to be stored at this node
     */
    public void setElement(T elem)
    {
        element = elem;
    }
}
```

This is my first time working with a linked list so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Posted to soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of the class `LinearNode` is missing in your question, but I assume you can do something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(top.toString());
    LinearNode<T> next = top.next();
    while(next != null) {
        sb.append("\n").append(next);
        next = next.next();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so just replace next() with getNext().

Comment: I changed top.next() to top.getNext() which helped with the two errors below this portion of code, but on the new StringBuilder portion of the code its giving me an error of: The constructor StringBuilder(LinearNode<T>) is undefined.